# How to find BOOT-SEL GPIO PIN?

Tags: pcb, bootloader, soc

I'm new to embedded linux and trying to explore it using Allwiner T113-i EVB.

Right now I'm struggling with boot process.

According to user manual BROM of SoC will try fetch boot code from SD card if Pin_Boot_Select != 0.

Due to lack of my experience i wasn't able to find those pins in documentation and on SoC.

Have anyone worked with Alwwiner's EVB ? Can you tell if I'm wrong ?

In https://whycan.com/files/202304/T113-I/T113-i_EVB_V1_0_20220507.pdf I can see that there are BOOT-SEL0 and BOOT-SEL1, but in PCB documentation i can't find it https://whycan.com/files/202304/T113-I/T113-I_EVB_V1_0_PCB.pdf

I'm apologizing in advance if my question seems strange or silly!

[image: image from documentation]

Link to User Manual - https://whycan.com/files/202304/T113-I/T113-i_User_Manual_V1.5.pdf

Link to DataSheet - https://whycan.com/files/202304/T113-I/T113-i_Datasheet_V1.4.pdf

Answer (score 1):

They are right here:[image]

"BOOT-SEL0" and "BOOT-SEL1"

Comment: The pins are H3 and F5 right ? I didn't find it in PCB doc file, also i didn't manage to find it in board

Comment: @savinposter Since it's a BGA you obviously will not be able to access the pin directly. But the pins are connected to some resistors that should be easily accessible. For example R18 and R20.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
I will try it out

Comment: Can you explain how I should apply 1 to those pins throught resistor? 
Simply connect it with wire to VCC ?